# Preventing Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attack for HttpServletRequest.getHeader()

Tags: java, security, xss

We are using java and spring boot. I want to read some header value from `HttpServletRequest`.

```
String header = request.getHeader("SomeHeader");
```

But our code quality tool is complaining like this:

```
The application's testMethod embeds untrusted data in the generated output with SomeHeader, at line 265 of src\main\java\com\test\poc\controller\Test.java. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.

The attacker would be able to alter the returned web page by simply providing modified data in the user input getHeader, which is read by the getCorrelationId method at line 265 of src\main\java\com\test\poc\controller\Test.java. This input then flows through the code straight to the output web page, without sanitization. 

This can enable a Reflected Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attack.
```

I have googled and tried with the following piece of code using owasp encoder dependency, but still the same problem persists.

```
String header = Encode.forJava(request.getHeader("SomeHeader"));
```

My method looks something like below:

```
private String testMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
  String header = Encode.forJava(request.getHeader("SomeHeader"));
  return header;

}
```

I will call the above method inside another method and want to verify if it's null or not

```
private void anotherMethod() {
      String header = testMethod();
      if (header != null) {
        //do something
      } else {
        //do something
      }
    }
```

Can anyone please guide how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Encoding is done on output not input so should be done at the point where you're outputting the value.

The encoder to use depends on the output format. If you're producing HTML, then you can use `Encode.forHtml`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated the question to give more clarity. Please guide me on where to apply the encoding logic inside ~testMethod()~ or ~anotherMethod()~ ?

Comment: @Ashok.N Is the header being written to HTML anywhere? Does `//do something` do something with the header or is it being used anywhere else?

Comment: Also, if you know the format of the header shouldn't contain characters other that a-z and spaces you can reject it completely if it's invalid in testMethod: `if(!header.matches("[a-zA-Z ]*")) throw new RuntimeException("Invalid header: " + header);`

Comment: Thanks! The header is not being written to HTML anywhere. My intention is simple. I have to extract the value of specific header(let's say the value of "SomeHeader" as per the question) from request object and see if it' null or empty. If so, just add logger info saying that the header value for "SomeHeader" is null. if it's not null, then use this header value for populating "HTTPHeaders" object further to hit some end point. But my code quality tool is having some problems with extracting header info from request object as described in the post.

Comment: @Ashok.N If it's not appearing in HTML anywhere, it's probably a false positive. `getHeader` without any output isn't a vulnerability.

Comment: Okay. Any workaround/suggestion to escape from it?

Comment: @Ashok.N You can add extra validation to check the header is in the format you expect before processing it. Otherwise it should be fine as is.